# Inversing a bitmatrix

Tags: c++, matrix-inverse

I need help inversing a bitmatrix, I have two functions that I am supposed to use with it. The first function swaps the rows, the other adds the two together. I need to use those two in the inverse function.

```
void Bitmatrix::Swap_Rows(int r1, int r2) {
    string temp;

    if(r1 < 0 || r2 < 0) return;
    if(r1 > M.size() || r2 > M.size()) return;
    temp = M[r1];
    M[r1] = M[r2];
    M[r2] = temp;
}

void Bitmatrix::R1_Plus_Equals_R2(int r1, int r2) {
    if(r1 < 0 || r2 < 0) return;
    if(r1 >= M.size() || r2 >= M.size()) return;

    for(int i = 0; i < M[1].size(); i++) {
        M[r1][i] = (M[r1][i] + M[r2][i]) % 2;
        M[r1][i] += '0';
    }
}
 //As of now I have this, but not sure how to do the rest.

Bitmatrix *Inverse(Bitmatrix *m) {
    if(m->Rows() != m->Cols()) return NULL; //if not square
    Bitmatrix Inv = new Bitmatrix(m->Rows(), m->Cols());
    for(int i = 0; i < Inv.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < Inv.size(); j++) {
            if(m[i][i] != '1') {
            R1_Plus_Equals_R2(

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your if statement are you sure it's supposed to be: `m[i][i] != '1'` shouldn't you be using the `j` counter from the inner for loop?

Comment: @FrancisCugler I was told: "Suppose you are at row i. If M[i][i] is not one, then find a row j where j > i such that M[j][i] equals one, and swap rows i and j. If you can't find such a row, the matrix is not invertible."

Comment: Oh okay I think I see what your saying... You are checking down the diagonal of the matrix to see if it has an identity property to it (so - to speak). I think it makes sense now; I'm just use to using both indexes.